# Is there a reason to prefer a private class method vs a non-exported helper function?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript has the concept of private class members (even if the distinction between private and public doesn't make it down to the JavaScript output).

```
// Pattern A

export class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.doSomething();
  }
  // private method
  private doSomething() {}
}
```

Alternatively, a method can be 'hidden' from consumers by simply not exporting it from the module.

```
//Pattern B

export class Foo {
  constructor() {
    doSomething();
  }
}
// non-exported function in module scope
function doSomething() { }
```

Within an all-Typescript codebase, is there a practical reason to prefer one of these patterns over the other?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing after reading The Google TypeScript style guide, which mentions “Consider converting private methods to non-exported functions within the same file but outside of any class, and moving private properties into a separate, non-exported class.” See: https://google.github.io/styleguide/tsguide.html

Answer (score 2):

I think the only important difference is that the private method has access to instance variables and methods via `this`, and the unexported helper function does not. I would be comfortable with either pattern.

You already noticed this, but for posterity I want to point out the compiled output of the version with the private method:

```
var Foo = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.doSomething();
    }
    // private method
    Foo.prototype.doSomething = function () { };
    return Foo;
}());
```

Typescript assigns `doSomething` to the `Foo` prototype, which is the same way that a public method is implemented. The "private" restriction is only enforced by Typescript at compile time. If this code where used in combination with plain Javascript code, the JS code would be able to call the private method just as easily as a public method. But in an all-Typescript project that does not matter.

When not using Typescript it is common to implement private methods by defining them in the class constructor. That creates a new copy of the method for each instance which closes over variables in the constructor, which might result in higher memory use. I think it is useful to understand that Typescript does not follow that pattern. In Typescript private methods have the same performance characteristics as public methods.

Answer (score 2):

The Pattern B is kinda not a typescript-way, it is more a javascript-way.

Within an all-Typescript codebase I would definitely prefer the Pattern A, since:

- it makes clear the intention of a developer
- it clearly states that `doSomething` belongs to the `Foo` class, i.e. it is semantically much better.
- refactoring is easier, you just move the whole class, not researching which functions you should also move.
- if one day you would need to access a member of `Foo` instance inside `doSomething` function, it would also be much easier, without messing with `.bind()`